# issues for birt plugin in eclipse if multiple user use it on linux at same time

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, birt

i am going to use BIRT plugin in eclipse in my linux operating system.
I want to know that whether there is any issue if multiple users use that plugin at the same time?
if so, what are the issues in using it?
if not, please tell me how many user can use that plug in at the same time?
please help.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with 'multiple users at the same time'? Are you running several instances of Eclipse? In that case, it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Actually i am working a multi-user system on which i want to use eclipse. Other users also want to use eclipse plugin at the same time when i am using the plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as Eclipse is installed correctly for a multi-user system there should not be a problem.

See this entry in the Eclipse help for install information: http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fmulti_user_installs.html

Comment: while running BIRT in linux it is giving problem while getting datasets if you have any solution please suggest